# What does "rows processed" in Oracle AWR report mean?

Tags: oracle, report, awr

I have an application which uses Oracle Database. I have several sql updates and selects in the application.

I gathered an AWR report on Oracle Database to diagnose some performance charasteristics of my application.

When I analyze the report by checking the "SQL ordered by Executions" statistics, I found out that one of my update query run 8985 times and row number processed by this query is 8,985. But, I have a select query and it run 8,985 times too but row number processed by this select statement is 8936.

My select query is right after the update query so it is expected that both queries' executed time is equal. What I wonder is, why my select query processed less row than its executed time value.

Thanks

Comment: Can your update change something that means the following select doesn't see that updated row any more?

Comment: I cannot share the exact sql statements due to regulations of my company but I can give a general scenario:

My update query is like this:

update table_1 set field_2=foo, field_3=bar, status_field=2 where status field=1 and rownum<2

My select query is like this:

select field_1 from table_1 where field_2=foo and field_3=bar

what am I trying to do here is saving some information to a random row table_1, updating status of the row to 2(which means occupied).After that I run a select query to retrieve the field_1 value of the row to find out which row is updated.

Answer (score 0):

conn / as sysdba

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

Specify the Report Type

```
AWR reports can be generated in the following formats. Please enter the
name of the format at the prompt. Default value is 'html'.

'html' HTML format (default)
'text' Text format
'active-html' Includes Performance Hub active report
```